# Fab повторное нажатие

Tags: java, android

Как мне сделать, чтобы при повторном нажатии на 
`FloatingActionButton` возвращалась изначальная запись? Вот код:

```
final FloatingActionButton btnKzt = (FloatingActionButton)header_0.findViewById(R.id.btn_kzt);
            btnKzt.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_kzt));
            btnKzt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btnKzt.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_usd));
                }
            });
```

При запуске приложения внутри `fab` стоит запись KZT, при нажатии запись меняется на USD. Как сделать чтобы при втором нажатии запись возвращала KZT ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

обьявите где-нибудь в основном классе поле `boolean isUSD = false`.
Дальше измените ваш код так:

```
final FloatingActionButton btnKzt = (FloatingActionButton)header_0.findViewById(R.id.btn_kzt);
            btnKzt.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_kzt));
            btnKzt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btnKzt.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(isUSD ? R.drawable.ic_kzt : R.drawable.ic_usd));
                    isUSD = !isUSD;
                }
            });
```

П. С.
Эта запись `isUSD ? R.drawable.ic_kzt : R.drawable.ic_usd` называется тернарный оператор. Она аналогична записи:

```
if(isUSD) {
    btnKzt.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_kzt);
} else {
    btnKzt.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_usd);
}
```

Но записывается значительно короче